# B&W movie of man developing super hearing

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Does anyone know of a B&W movie where a man develops super hearing? It gets so bad that he needs an operation to stop it. Just as they are about to operate he hears aliens voices - but the movie ends and we don't know if the doctors operate before he hears the message.

Comment: This seems to be a short black and White made for TV Movie. I do remember it, but unfortunately cannot remember what is was called. It may be one of the Out of the unknown series.

Comment: I have been looking for this for years. I saw it in the early 60s. I thought it might be a Tales of Tomorrow or a Science Fiction Theatre episode, but it doesn't match any of their synopses in IMDB. It definitely seemed like a half-hour episode of one of the old anthology shows. There is a climactic scene shortly before they wheel him out for the operation where he turns his lamp toward the wall and sees the shadows of the aliens' transparent bodies.